# JavaFX Setup on Raspbian Jessie Lite

Tags: raspbian, javafx

I've Downloaded 2017-04-10-raspbian-jessie-lite.img to run my JavaFX application. But it's not working.

On Google I've noticed that Java8 doesn't have support for JavaFX on ARM like Raspberry, but we can setup Gluon OpenJFX.

So far i did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-jdk

mkdir /home/pi/Downloads
wget http://download.gluonhq.com/javafxports/embedded/armv6hf-sdk-8.60.9.zip
unzip armv6hf-sdk-8.60.9.zip
```

But I don't know whre to put the unziped files. The Gluon documentation is not updated, and I don't have skills to know what i have to do to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the files as follows:

```
armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar -> jre/lib/ext/
armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/arm/* -> jre/lib/arm/
armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/javafx.platform.properties -> jre/lib/
armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/javafx.properties -> jre/lib/
armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/jfxswt.jar -> jre/lib/
```

See http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_embedded

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the Gluon version I just used the openjfx package and it seems to work. The media parts just down work.